# Ionic2 Custom Auth InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I'm a beginner to Ionic2 and currently studying about Ionic2 Auth Service.

I cannot understand some parts of description in the documentation.

Why do we need InAppBrowser in custom login??

In basic login documentation, there is no mention about inAppBrowser but suddenly

in custom login documentation, inAppBrowser comes out.

Can you explain why inAppBrowser is needed in this circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that all auth2 need inAppBrowser or not but in my latest project i used dropbox api, which uses auth2 for authentication. In this authentication process we have to open a specific URL provided by dropbox with their clientID. This URL then return a dropbox build-in login screen if user not logged-in. So we need inAppBrowser to display that login screen and other webpages after that login to display in our app. We cannot create that dropbox built-in process in our app.